# How to do a find with a regex and jump to a specific position within the match

Tags: regular-expression, find

For example:

I have several lines starting with `:q:`, which I want to jump to:

```
:q: regex syntax
(...)
:q: regex examples
(...)
```

Now I want to jump to the start of `regex syntax` or `regex example` with a specific regex find expression via `/`. Is this possible?

Why not just use `W` to jump to it? Well, it would just be nice to jump to each expression with the use of `n` and `N`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\zs` (and it's complement, `\ze`), e.g.

```
/:q: \zs
```

should work for your example (assuming there is exactly 1 space after the second `:`)

It works by setting the start (or end in the case of `\ze`) of the matching text to a point somewhere in the middle of the regex. Check out `:h \zs`, it has a much better description than I can give, with additional examples.

Comment: Haha, I have written a whole custom command and mapped it in the meantime, but this works so much better, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the location in which the cursor is left after a search by using an [offset](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#search-offset):

You can either an "end" or "start" offset for your specific example:

```
/:q:/e+2
/:q:/s+4
```

See [`:help search-offset`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#search-offset) for more details.

You can apply these offsets retroactively to an existing search by using an empty regular expression:

```
/:q:
//e+2
```

Comment: +1, this is a better solution than mine if, as in this case, the offset is a fixed number of characters.